# Induct on two variables?

Tags: isabelle, induction

Given a function that generates a list of identical items I wish to prove that the generated lists consist the given natural number at all positions independent of list length.

```
fun pattern_n :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list" where
"pattern_n _ 0  = []" |
"pattern_n n lng = n # (pattern_n n (lng - 1))"

lemma pattern_n_1: "lng > 0 ∧ pos ≥ 0 ∧ pos < lng ∧ n ≥ 0 ⟹ (pattern_n n lng ! pos) = n"
```

It seems obvious that the proof should be based on induction on the length of the generated list but pos also seems to be an induction variable candidate. I'd appreciate any help on how to proceed with this proof.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work/where were you stuck? Try to apply induction as you think is correct. What happens?

Comment: ThreeFx, I've tried to induct on lng by apply(induction lng arbitrary: n) and apply(simp) after which Isabelle still requires a proof for the induction step. In the case of a simple function like pattern_n what  more knowledge could be added to prove the induction step? My only idea is that somehow the item position should also be used as an induction variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `pattern_n` is equivalent to the function `replicate` from the standard library (theory `List`). The standard library also contains the theorem `nth_replicate` for the function `replicate` that is nearly identical to the theorem that you are trying to prove:

```
fun pattern_n :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list" where
  "pattern_n _ 0  = []" |
  "pattern_n n lng = n # (pattern_n n (lng - 1))"
    
lemma "pattern_n n k = replicate k n"
  by (induction k) auto
    
thm nth_replicate
```

---

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, you can use induction to prove the result. Usually it is more convenient to use the definition in the form that is provided by the function `pattern_n'` below, because the theorems that are generated automatically when you define the function are more consistent with this form.

```
fun pattern_n :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list" where
  "pattern_n _ 0  = []" |
  "pattern_n n lng = n # (pattern_n n (lng - 1))"

fun pattern_n' :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list" where
  "pattern_n' n 0  = []" |
  "pattern_n' n (Suc lng) = n # (pattern_n' n lng)"

lemma "pattern_n n lng = pattern_n' n lng"
  by (induct lng) auto

lemma pattern_n_1_via_replicate: 
  "pos < lng ⟹ (pattern_n val lng) ! pos = val"
proof(induct lng arbitrary: pos)
  case 0 then show ?case by simp
next
  case (Suc lng) then show ?case by (fastforce simp: less_Suc_eq_0_disj)
qed
```

---

Isabelle version: Isabelle2020

Comment: xanonec, thanks for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't help me to understand the main point. I'm working on pattern generators more complex than this one, such that replicate couldn't act as a substitute.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly Thank you for your comment. I provided an update. Also, it may still be useful for you to use my first answer to infer the methodology that was used for the proof of the identical theorem in the standard library.

Comment: xanonec, pattern_n_1_via_replicate is what I was looking for. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: An additional question: where could I learn more about rules like less_Suc_eq_0_disj? I find nothing about this one in Isabelle materials and other similar rules seem to be very loosely documented.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly `less_Suc_eq_0_disj` is defined in the theory `Nat`. In case if you did not know, if you use jEdit, then you should be able to hover over `less_Suc_eq_0_disj` in the proof and use `cntrl+lmb` (may be different for different OS) to quickly navigate to the theory where the rule is specified. As a side note, there are many different ways to prove the theorem that you were looking to prove. Perhaps, the best methodology can be inferred if you study the proof of `nth_replicate` from the standard library, as I already mentioned in my first comment.